# BigQuery schema table to json with Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I need to have a Python equivalence of this BigQuery `bq show --format=prettyjson myproject:mydataset.mytable`.

Is there a way to do it with the BigQuery API in Python ?

I tried this in Python:

```
view_ref = self._client.dataset(dataset.dataset_id).table(table.table_id)
table_obj = self._client.get_table(view_ref)

dict_schema = []
for schema_field in table_obj.schema:
    dict_schema.append({
        'name': schema_field.name,
        'mode': schema_field.mode,
        'type': schema_field.field_type
   })
```

It almost works; I just don't have the nested schema field/

Thanks for replies and have a nice day.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get convert your table schema to json simply using the [schema_to_json()](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html) method. It needs two attributes, *schema_list* and *destination*, respectively.

I exemplified your case using a public dataset with nested data and used [StringIO()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) just to show how the schema will be.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import io

client = bigquery.Client()

project = 'bigquery-public-data'
dataset_id = 'samples'
table_id = 'shakespeare'

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id, project=project)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
table = client.get_table(table_ref)


f = io.StringIO("")
client.schema_to_json(table.schema, f)
print(f.getvalue())
```

And the output:

```
[
  {
    "description": "A single unique word (where whitespace is the delimiter) extracted from a corpus.",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "word",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "description": "The number of times this word appears in this corpus.",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "word_count",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "description": "The work from which this word was extracted.",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "corpus",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "description": "The year in which this corpus was published.",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "corpus_date",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  }
]
```

Which is the same as the output displayed when using the command `!bq show --format=prettyjson bigquery-public-data:samples.wikipedia | jq '.schema.fields'`

Comment: Getting a mypy error: Argument 2 to "schema_to_json" of "Client" has incompatible type "StringIO"; expected "Union[str, bytes, PathLike[str], PathLike[bytes]]" with this approach. Any suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: ```client.schema_to_json(table.schema, f)```
AttributeError: 'TableListItem' object has no attribute 'schema'